# Difference between linear queue and circular queue

Tags: java, data-structures

I am new to Data Structure. I have gone through the implementation of linear queue after taking reference from many books.

This is my implementation for linear queue.

```
public class QueueObject {

    private Object[] heads;
    private int rearPointer, frontPointer, currentNumber;

    public QueueObject(int capacity) {
        heads = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (currentNumber == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return (currentNumber == heads.length);
    }


    public void push(Object o){
        if(isFull()){
            return;
        }

   // means we are at last position (deal with wrap around)
        if(rearPointer >= heads.length){
            rearPointer = 0;
        }
        heads[rearPointer++] = o;
        currentNumber++;
    }


    public Object pop(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

 // dealing with wrap around
        if(frontPointer >= heads.length){
            frontPointer = 0;
        }
        Object o = heads[frontPointer++];
        currentNumber--;
        return o;
    }

}
```

Now my question is does handling wrap around make it circular queue instead of linear queue ?

Comment: What you have there is a circular queue (ring buffer). A linear queue always adds at the back and removes from the front. Implementing a linear queue in an array is inefficient because every time you remove an item you have to move all the other items up to fill the empty spot.

Comment: Thanks, actually I found this implementation in two three books and got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a Ring Buffer.

> Circular Queue is a linear data structure in which the operations are performed based on FIFO (First In First Out) principle and the last position is connected back to the first position to make a circle.

See a detailed explanation on http://btechsmartclass.com/DS/U2_T10.html and https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-applications-of-circular-queues-in-C